# Is it possible to detect normal beacons using Core Bluetooth concept?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have already worked with ibeacons using Core Bluetooth. It detects iBeacons and works fine. Now I would like to know that "Will CoreBluetooth detects normal beacons"?

Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two types of beacons. 1. ibeacon (it will use uuid to detect) 2. Beacon (it does not have uuid)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `CoreBluetooth` will not let you read iBeacon identifiers, so it is pretty much useless for working with them.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html) for details.

I am not sure what you mean by "normal" beacons.  You will need to clarify.